# How do i display the text with the list i have stored ? It is not assigning in UI text ...?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

[image]
here is the code

The part which is commented here is giving error when i play .
it isnot assigning in the ui tmp .

I tried using non canvas prefab for Cards , but i want it in ui only.
Sorry for not addresing the problem clearly(i am not good at coding ).

Comment: paste your code

Comment: For several reasons, don't post just pictures of code. Post the code as text, formatted as code.

Comment: Also, you say that it's giving an error but you haven't provided the error message. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to ask a question properly.

Comment: [**Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the TMP Gui variables to TMP_Text if you are using Text variables & assign them in the editor.

This could also be one of your card values being null. Try debugging and seeing for yourself, if you dont know how to debug check this out https://youtu.be/wt2YdrUlzgg